# php file_get_contents

Tags: php, url, file-get-contents

I have 2 domains on the same server and I am trying to access a file on one that is perms 777.
I can use file_get_contents with a url but can't do so with a path. What can be preventing this?

Comment: Please show your code and the error message you get.

Comment: Are you using the full path? eg: /var/www/vhosts/test.com/myfile.png

Comment: Are you using a directive such as [open_basedir](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir)?

Comment: Check if the user running PHP has access to the directories leading to the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This really depends on a few different things. If the file is in a seperate folder, outside of the user folder of one site, than it is possible that open_basedir is in effect and is blocking the read attempt. I believe this is the most likely culprit.